# Sonar keeps failing after the first successful run

Tags: java, sonarqube

The first run worked fine, then I realized that it was missing a few rules. So I fixed all the problems and added the new rules then re-run sonar. Since then sonar will not work, it just keeps failing.

Every time it gives me this error:

```
org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.ArchiverException: The source must not be a directory.
```

The command I used is:

```
mvn clean install -Psonar sonar:sonar
```

Any idea what could have cause this?

```
org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.ArchiverException: The source must not be a directory.
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractUnArchiver.validate(AbstractUnArchiver.java:185)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractUnArchiver.extract(AbstractUnArchiver.java:118)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.dependency.AbstractDependencyMojo.unpack(AbstractDependencyMojo.java:258)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.dependency.fromConfiguration.UnpackMojo.unpackArtifact(UnpackMojo.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.dependency.fromConfiguration.UnpackMojo.execute(UnpackMojo.java:94)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.executeForkedExecutions(MojoExecutor.java:365)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:199)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:85)
        at org.sonar.maven3.Maven3PluginExecutor.concreteExecute(Maven3PluginExecutor.java:49)
        at org.sonar.batch.AbstractMavenPluginExecutor.execute(AbstractMavenPluginExecutor.java:49)
        at org.sonar.batch.AbstractMavenPluginExecutor.execute(AbstractMavenPluginExecutor.java:38)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.InitializersExecutor.executeMavenPlugin(InitializersExecutor.java:73)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.InitializersExecutor.execute(InitializersExecutor.java:60)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.Phases.execute(Phases.java:90)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ProjectModule.doStart(ProjectModule.java:143)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.start(Module.java:83)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchModule.analyze(BatchModule.java:111)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchModule.analyze(BatchModule.java:106)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchModule.analyze(BatchModule.java:106)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchModule.doStart(BatchModule.java:101)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.start(Module.java:83)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapModule.doStart(BootstrapModule.java:102)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.start(Module.java:83)
        at org.sonar.batch.Batch.execute(Batch.java:100)
        at org.sonar.maven3.SonarMojo.executeBatch(SonarMojo.java:146)
        at org.sonar.maven3.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:136)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.executeMojo(Bootstraper.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.start(Bootstraper.java:65)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:90)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)

[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2:04.569s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Feb 23 11:19:25 EST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 89M/705M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The requested profile "sonar" could not be activated because it does not exist.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.3:unpack (unpack-pinkcommon-tools) on project pinkcommon-ejb: Error unpacking file: C:\cygwin\home\GIT\trunk\pinkcommo
n\pinkcommon-tools\target\classes to: C:\cygwin\home\GIT\trunk\pinkcommon\pinkcommon-ejb\target\classes
[ERROR] org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.ArchiverException: The source must not be a directory.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (default-cli) on project webapps: Can not execute Sonar: Unable to execute maven plugin: Exception during execution of org
.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin:2.5.1:cobertura -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
```

Comment: You should give a more comprehensive stack-trace, only one line can't help to know what's wrong.
And you could also show your profile named "sonar".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is not with sonar.  I think that if you just run 'install' you will also have the same problem.

You are using the dependency plugin and you might have configured it wrong.  This is the interesting part of the maven output:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.3:unpack (unpack-pinkcommon-tools) on project pinkcommon-ejb: Error unpacking file: C:\cygwin\home\GIT\trunk\pinkcommo
n\pinkcommon-tools\target\classes to: C:\cygwin\home\GIT\trunk\pinkcommon\pinkcommon-ejb\target\classes
[ERROR] org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.ArchiverException: The source must not be a directory.
```

Without you pom.xml configuration there is not much more people can do to help you.

Comment: @Joe Chen: I agree with tom, we won't be able to help you without the POM. What's more, you can see in the stack trace that the "sonar" profile does not exist in your POM, so there's definitely something wrong there.

Comment: @tom the install works fine actually, no problems there. it is weird that sonar ran fine the first time, then all subsequent runs failed. so now im actually running sonar on individual projects. here is a screenshot http://i.imgur.com/lHkL7.png..

Comment: I don't know why the first run worked but I know that certain maven plugins add a source-folder when they run.  For example, the Jspc plugin adds a source folder target/jsp-sources.  If I can take a guess, I think the dependency plugin is adding a source folder when maven runs that sonar is not liking at all.

Answer (score 1):

As per http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+Maven, you need to add Sonar settings to you Maven settings.xml file.

You should edit settings.xml file, located into $MAVEN_HOME/conf or ~/.m2, and the database parameters to be used as well as the Sonar server URL.

```
<settings>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>sonar</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <!-- EXAMPLE FOR MYSQL -->
                <sonar.jdbc.url>
                  jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8
                </sonar.jdbc.url>
                <sonar.jdbc.driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</sonar.jdbc.driverClassName>
                <sonar.jdbc.username>sonar</sonar.jdbc.username>
                <sonar.jdbc.password>sonar</sonar.jdbc.password>

                <!-- optional URL to server. Default value is http://localhost:9000 -->
                <sonar.host.url>
                  http://myserver:9000
                </sonar.host.url>
            </properties>
        </profile>
     </profiles>
</settings>
```

Comment: I do not see how this is related to the problem.  Yes he is missing the sonar profile he is trying to use but that is not the main issue here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is about Cobertura coverage plugin for Sonar. This is a 5-year-old bug of maven-dependency-plugin where Cobertura gives the above error if unpack goal is used. See the following Jira tickets:

- [The source must not be a directory](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MDEP-98)
- [ArchiverException when using maven dependency plugin in multi-module
  projects](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MDEP-194)

In my case I found workaround to use unpack-dependencies goal instead unpack inside the maven-dependency-plugin.